# Are there any well symbols for ArcGIS Silverlight/WPF?

Tags: symbology, silverlight

I'm looking for some standard map symbols for a silverlight app.  Does anyone know where I could find these?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The [ArcGIS API for Microsoft Silverlight Symbol Gallery](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/SymbolGalleryWeb/start.htm) has several that look like examples from your list.  Check the ESRI Cartography Marker Symbols and the Custom Marker Symbols.

Comment: Hey Seth, thank for responding see my reply to MarcBate.

Answer (score 1):

ESRI has symbols similar to these, though you might need a bit of editing to create a few of those.

http://downloads2.esri.com/support/documentation/ao_/Petroleum.pdf

http://downloads2.esri.com/support/documentation/ao_/Petroleum_UK.pdf

All the ESRI symbols can be found in pdf form [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/product-documentation?fa=viewDoc&PID=80&MetaID=854), sometimes it's much easier to browse them in a pdf than in ArcMap.

Comment: Thanks wwnick, but I was hoping to avoid having to do any editing.

Comment: Petroleum Styles are in Style Manager in ArcGIS - you can add to the style (with .eps etc) but cannot export them - @Kirk found this http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2456&t=286607 not much help and likely you have read it before.

Answer (score 1):

Don't the symbols in the various resource dictionaries in ESRI's Silverlight [Symbol Gallery](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/2.2/samples/SymbolGalleryWeb/start.htm) close enough for your needs, or do you need those exact symbols?

The [ESRI Silverlight Viewer](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/silverlightwpf/archive/2011/03/05/ArcGIS-Viewer-for-Microsoft-Silverlight-1.0-Beta-now-available_2100_.aspx) has several of these images in the \Images\Marker Symbols\ directory of the sites you create with their builder.

Couldn't you just write an app that saves all the marker symbols in a *.Style file to *.PNG files?   How about just copying and pasting the individual symbols off that image you included here and save as individual PNG files?  You'll probably want a better quality scan or whatever you used since those are a bit small and the second column is askew.

Comment: Thanks, since so much of Esri's revenue comes from oil exploration industry (where silverlight/wpf predominates) I was expecting there to be one already developed specifically for this.  Are we now relying on overseas oil symbols too?  I'll probably stick with the [getlegendinfo](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/soap/SOAP_Map_GetLegendInfo.htm) for now.